# Hosting the application at multiple places with single url

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, okta-api, aws-route53

We want to host our web application at different places to be in compliance with GDPR laws etc. Though the application is hosted in different places (each place has seperate server and database), we would like to have only one single url for the application and the customer should be routed to the instance where his records are added.
For example: If our application is hosted in Europe and US, when a customer from Europe tries to access the application, all the requests should be routed to the Server in European region.

We are using OKTA for the login validation. Application is hosted in AWS and we have an ngnix server which acts as load balancer for routing the requests to appropriate ec-2 instance. Can you please help out how this can be effectively done.

We are exploring the effective ways for detecting which part the user belongs to and redirect to that instance. Can we get some assistance on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Route53 Geolocation routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy-geo.html). Seems fit with your use case.

> Geolocation routing lets you choose the resources that serve your traffic based on the geographic location of your users, meaning the location that DNS queries originate from. For example, you might want all queries from Europe to be routed to an Elastic Load Balancing load balancer in the Frankfurt Region.

Comment: Thank you very much Izaadev for the quick response. The suggestion you have given addresses maximum scenarios but one concern I have i.e, for example if a customer from Europe went to USA and accessed the application from there. As his details will not be in USA instances, login to application will be failed right. We would like to address those scenarios as well.

Comment: There's no way to achieve that with a Route 53 routing policy. One option is to have  a global user login component that routes the user to the region he/she belongs to.

Comment: Thank you so much Andres for the prompt response. Can you please elaborate about this global user login component.  Is it something that can be configured at AWS or at OKTA or some other 3rd party component etc or is it something that we need to configure on our own.

Comment: If you're utilizing Okta's app dashboard, maybe you can group your users based on region. Then from the app dashboard just show the 'app' that directs them to their respective endpoint.

`User login via Okta
-> User is member of Europe group
-> App dashboard show the application to Europe endpoint`

This is just an idea with little knowledge I have about Okta.